# The most efficient (but also legible) way to only add two numbers if they're actually numbers?

Tags: javascript

`value1` and `value2` are pulled in from HTML `INPUT` elements, just to provide some context. Right now I've got this:

```
if (!!value1 && !!value2) {
  return parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

Is there some more efficient way to write this? Like some magical one-liner?

Comment: Do you want to verify that the input are numeric strings? Your `!!value1` check doesn't do that, so I'm not sure if you're looking for a solution that *does* do that, or a shorter solution that does what your code actually does.

Comment: @apsillers Good point. I should use `isNaN`

Comment: `return (+value1) + (+value2) || 0`

Comment: @adeneo Whoa! Bonus! You wanna put that as an official answer?

Comment: Nah, it's basically the same as PhilVargs answer, just added a logical "or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming they will be strings of numbers or numbers, not letters:

```
return +value1 + +value2;
```

Comment: Wow! Just putting a `+` before a variable works the same as `parseInt`??

Comment: Just be aware that this will return `NaN` rather than 0 if `value1` or `value2` is a string that cannot be interpreted as a number.

Comment: yes. same as parseInt. i made sure to disclaim that the inputs have to be parseable numbers. the unary operator has the benefit of turning an empty string to 0 though, which is what his bang-bang is checking for.

Comment: Right. It's just not equivalent to OP's original code. But I see that OP posted a comment that the original code should actually return `NaN` anyway, so your answer actually fixes things.

Comment: it should actually return 0 if either is a string.

Comment: Even if it's a string containing numbers? Then why use parseInt

Comment: @adeneo parseInt or the preceding + is needed, because if value1 is 88 and value2 is 12, without parseInt you get a result of 8812.

Comment: Well yes, because an elements value is always a string, that's why the statement *"always return 0 if it's a string"* seemed strange.

Comment: @adeneo I meant as opposed to returning "NaN"

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to worry about validation:

`return +value1 + +value2;`

else:

`return value1 && value2 ? parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) : 0;`

Comment: What about: `return !(isNaN(value1) || isNaN(value2)) ? +value1 + +value2 : 0;`

Comment: That looks like a very good way of condensing it as well, plus adds better validation.